# how can i keep several linux virtual containers in sync

Tags: linux, automation, deployment

I have one website which initially we were hosting externally and we three environments like

`DEV TEST UAT PROD`

Now they have given us `4 virtual containers where i have to install everything myself.'

I have installed it on my home computer but i don't know how i will kepp that same on 4 machines.

I am thinking of using make files but don't know

I have heard of `chef and puppet` but i don't know them.

Is there any other alternative or i have to use puppet or chef

Answer (score 0):

You can try so-called "SSH multiplexsers" to manually run `yum` or `apt` on multiple machines in parallel.

- http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Debian/CoolTools/SSH/parallel-ssh.html